# Delete articles from db decrease/increase order php

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I wish you a new happy year! So I have 3 articles for example and each of them has an order, like 1,2,3. If I want to delete the last article for example, the order of the other articles still remain the same 1,2. But if I delete the first article the orders of the others should decrease with 1 and if I delete the middle one only the order of the last article should decrease.
Now how to do this in php? I refer to delete in database
Any idea is appreciated.
I don't have any code yet because I wanted to find first a solution, I only give the id of the article, the order and the category from which it belongs:

```
 if($_POST['actiune'] == 'updateArticle'){
        $id_article = $_GET['id'];
        $ord = $_GET['order'];
        $categ = $_GET['categ'];


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an update after each delete. Something like:

`UPDATE [ArticleTable] SET [OrderColumn]=[OrderColumn]-1 WHERE [OrderColumn]>=[ORDERVALUE_FROM_DELETED_ITEM]`

Comment: That looks like SQL-Server syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: The [] are not part of the synthax these are just placeholders for example if your table is called Article and your column is called OrderC and you deleted an article with the value 2 the Statement looks like:
`UPDATE Article SET OrderC=OrderC-1 WHEREOrderC>=2`

Comment: lol, your placeholder syntax is identical to real SQL-Server syntax, so I hope you understand why I made that mistake. I usually just make up table and column names when I post answers like this.

Comment: The [] are not part of the synthax these are just placeholders for example if your table is called Article and your column is called OrderC and you deleted an article with the value 2 the Statement looks like:
`UPDATE Article SET OrderC=OrderC-1 WHERE OrderC>=2`

Comment: Yeah i should change that. I only use this, because sometimes people believe they should use my made up names and than wonder why the statement fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer